# How to solve React "too many re-renders" error

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm learning about React hooks and have the following code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {

  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [person, setPerson] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getPerson();
  }, []);

  const getPerson = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("https://api.randomuser.me");
    const data = await response.json();
    setPerson(data.results);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => getPerson(), setCount(count + 1)}>Click Me</button>
      <div>{person.map(person => person.name.first)}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When I click the 'Click Me' button, I want the counter to update and the API call to be made to fetch a random person. Individually, both of these bits of code work. However, when I try to do both at the same time, I receive this error: `Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.`

I am new to React and can't figure why this is. I have added the `[]` as the second argument in the UseEffect method which I thought might stop the page constantly re-rendering.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: I think you have an syntax error? `onClick={() => getPerson(), setCount(count + 1)}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if you copied the code wrong to your question, but here is something that will make it better.

```
  ...
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => { getPerson(); setCount(count + 1)}}>Click Me</button>
      <div>{person.map(person => person.name.first)}</div>
    </div>
  );
```

This will work, but at the same time, isn't good, maybe you want to increase the count only when the resquet finishes?

So what you can do is use `.then`

```
onClick={() => { getPerson().then(() => setCount(count + 1))}}
```

Comment: Thanks so much @vencovsky :) Do you mind telling me why using .then is better?

Comment: @juemura7 with `.then`, `setCount` will only execute when `getPerson` finishes, wich means only after the request to the api gets back and you call `setPerson(data.results)`. If you don't use `.then`, the user can click alot of times, the counter will update, but `setPerson(data.results)` can never be called (because of some error or because the user internet is too slow). Without `.then` isn't a problem, but with it, the counter will be synced with the data.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't correct because `useEffect` is nothing but similar to `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`. If you are updating state in this method and not restricting it then it will cause infinite rendering.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [person, setPerson] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // You need to restrict it at some point
    // This is just dummy code and should be replaced by actual
    if (person.length === 0) {
        getPerson();
    }
  }, []);

  const getPerson = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("https://api.randomuser.me");
    const data = await response.json();
    setPerson(data.results);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => {getPerson(); setCount(count + 1);}}>Click Me</button>
      <div>{person.map(person => person.name.first)}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you @MilindAgrawal :) Is the `if (person.length === 0)` necessary? The code works without this line in and wondered if it is needed ?

Comment: No, it's not really required and can be removed. Sorry for the late response.